# How to access a website running on docker after closing the debug on Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, docker, debugging, docker-compose, containers

I build a very simple web app and web api on .net core and configured the docker-compose to get them to communicate over the same network correctly.

On  visual studio, when I hit play on the Docker Compose project, it runs fine, both the web app and the web api work and communicate correctly.

On the Docker Desktop app i see them running (green).
[image]

But when I close/stop the debugger on VS I can't access the websites anymore even though the containers are still running. I thought docker worked as a sort of IIS.

Am I misunderstanding the docker capabilities or do I need to run them again from a *CLI* or publish them somewhere or what?
I thought the fact the containers are up and running should mean they're live for me to navigate to.

Help me out over here please.

Comment: what is the output of ` docker ps -a`  ?

Comment: The result of 'docker ps -a' is this ----> 560f78689902        moviedecisionweb:dev   "C:\\remote_debugger\\…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:52002->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:52001->443/tcp   mdweb ----> 1cd7f72426fe        moviedecisionapi:dev   "C:\\remote_debugger\\…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:52005->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:52004->443/tcp   mdapi

Comment: so if you type "http://localhost:52002" nothing will come in the browser ?

Comment: today i tried running 'docker-compose up -d' after deleting the dockercompose container instead of running through VS and it worked. I can't access it through the names though. If I try http://mdapi/api/Movie it can't resolve the mdapi. And if I do it through VS it works

Comment: I think your api is accessable with port "52004" so it is `https://localhost:52004` or `http://localhost:52005` , or I got you wrong ?

Comment: @LinPy yes, I can access it through those urls but i need to access them through the original url i had, http://mdapi/ and http://mdweb/.

Comment: Then you need to edit your hosts file to rsolve the name correctly

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61466334/why-is-my-docker-container-asp-net-core-app-not-available-after-ending-debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, unless there is some special routing happening, the fact that the containers are running means your services are available.

You can see the ports being exposed from the `docker ps -a` command:

```
CONTAINER_ID: 560f78689902 
IMAGE: moviedecisionweb:dev 
COMMAND: "C:\\remote_debugger\\…"
CREATED: About a minute ago
STATUS: Up About a minute 
PORTS: 0.0.0.0:52002->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:52001->443/tcp 
NAMES: mdweb

CONTAINER_ID: 1cd7f72426fe
IMAGE: moviedecisionapi:dev
COMMAND: "C:\\remote_debugger\\…"
CREATED: About a minute ago
STATUS: Up About a minute
PORTS: 0.0.0.0:52005->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:52004->443/tcp
NAMES: mdapi
```

Based on the provided output, you have two docker containers running.

I'm assuming the ports 80 & 443 are serving the HTTP & HTTPS services (respectively) from your app/s.

Based on this...

For container "mdweb", you should be able to access the docker services from your docker host machine (PC) via:

- http://localhost:52002
- https://localhost:52001

For container "mdapi", you should be able to access the docker services from your docker host machine (PC) via:

- http://localhost:52005
- https://localhost:52004

I believe you can use `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` (but not `0.0.0.0`) interchangeably in the above.

You cannot use the hostnames "mdweb" or "mdapi" from your docker HOST machine - unless you have explicitly setup your DNS to handle these names. However you can use these hostnames if you are inside a docker container on the same docker network.

If you provide more information (e.g. your `docker-compose.yml`), we could help you further...

Comment: 0.0.0.0 can't be reached from the host machine actually because it's not a "valid" IP address. Docker uses 0.0.0.0 to refer to all network interfaces from a container. Each container has its own 127.0.0.1 that refers to the same container but 0.0.0.0 refers to the host machine's all network interfaces. Therefore, your assumption of "you should be able to access the docker services from your docker host machine (PC) via http://0.0.0.0:52002 & https://0.0.0.0:52001" is not correct.